# BigQuery Flatten or Unnest Repeated Field

Tags: arrays, flatten, unnest

I am new to BigQuery and not familiar with dealing with tables that have repeated rows. I am aware that in Standard SQL in BigQuery that it will automatically handle the repeated rows, and I have seen how that works. However, I am trying to bring the data into a visualization tool that isn't able to handle tables with repeated rows.

What I am trying to do is run a query that is going to save the data in a view with the data flatten (legacy language)/unnested (standard language). All I am trying to include in the result of the query is the fields:

- id
- itemizations (this is the repeated field)

Could you give me some input on how to accomplish this or what other information you might need to help provide an answer to this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wanted to bump this to the top to see if someone might have some input.